# i want to compare two percents for one variable from two independent samples

Tags: chi-squared-test

[image]

can you explain which test had used to calculate the p value in this table ?
how they compare between percents?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, some form of t-test.

For each of the variables, the test is conducted with the null hypothesis of "the mean is the same in the 2 groups" and the alternative hypothesis of "the mean is different".

And the p-values you see are the results of those tests.